# How can I create major Tick marks every hour using a columns local timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter

I convert json data into a dataframe.  The dataframe contains UTC time stamps which Ive converted to loacal time.  I create a bar graph but there are way too many tick mark labes.  I wanna keep allof the ticks but only label every hour or so.  Do I need to convert my timestamp?  Im super new to python, I have tried too much and cant figure this out.

```
from dateutil import tz
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'

data1 = df[['requestId', 'assignTime', 'queueTime', 'finishTime', 'result']] #create table data1
data1["waitTime"] = None  # add new empty columns
data1["duration"] = None

data1['assignTime'] = (pd.to_datetime(data1['assignTime']) # convert utc time to local time
                     .dt.tz_convert('America/New_York'))    
data1['queueTime'] = (pd.to_datetime(data1['queueTime']) # convert utc time to local time
                     .dt.tz_convert('America/New_York'))    
data1['finishTime'] = (pd.to_datetime(data1['finishTime']) # convert utc time to local time
                     .dt.tz_convert('America/New_York'))    

data1['waitTime'] = (data1['assignTime'] - data1['queueTime']).astype('timedelta64[m]') #calculate wait time and duration
data1['duration'] = (data1['finishTime'] - data1['assignTime']).astype('timedelta64[m]')

data1 = data1.sort_values(by="queueTime")#sort the data by queue time chronologically

y = data1.waitTime
x = data1.queueTime


ax = data1[['waitTime','duration']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Jobs", figsize=(15, 15), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Time of day", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Minutes", fontsize=12)



plt.show()
```

Here is some of my data

[image]

Comment: Can you check if the code is compiling and post a working one with your difficulties?

Comment: It ouputs a graph, the problem is, there are too many labels on the x-axis and they are all garbled

Comment: I could not compile your posted code. Please post your working one. For example, what is `df`?